# Re-writing an ODE by Multiplying with a Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I have the following equation

$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg( \frac{1}{(1+ x^2)^2} \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg) + \lambda x^2 y =0 \ .$$

I'm trying to re-write it so that it looks more like a physically relevant equation:

$$ -\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} - i  V_1 (x) \frac{d \psi}{d x} + V_2 (x) \psi = \lambda \psi $$

I think you can do this by multiplying the equation by some function $f(x)$ and and then doing a change of coordinates and re-defining the wave function as $\psi (x) = f(x) y(x)$, but what should $f$, $V_1$ and $V_2$ be in order to do this?

Comment: What is the more physically relevant equation? Are you trying to make this appear like the Hamiltonian for a charged particle?

Comment: No, trying to make it look like ODE for wave function of a particle in a potential $V = V_1 p + V_2$ where $p = mv$ is the momentum of the particle.

Comment: I mean, that *is* an electromagnetic potential even if you aren't calling it that.

Comment: Does the independent variable $x$ in the final equation have to be the same independent variable $x$ in the first equation? This would be good context to include in your post: what exactly it is you're doing and what your constraints are. Because a change of variable would certainly help massage the process if it is allowed.

Comment: Ah yes, I have added that.  The $x$ can be different as there is a change of coordinates before the re-definition of wave function.

Comment: How would you end up with the imaginary "i" in your question when everything starts off as real?